# Threading / While Loop with python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make this script run every 30 minutes. at the moment it only runs once - a bit confused why it isn't running many more times.

Any idea on where I'm going wrong with my code? Basically this script is taking data from an API, in XML, and then putting it into a csv file.

Trying to use Threading to make it run every so many seconds - running it on pythonanywhere at the moment - and it will only run once. A little bit confused why that would be!

I also have tried using a while loop - put a example of what i've tried near the threading code.

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request
import csv
import threading

#Pickle is not needed
#append to list next

def handleLeg(leg):
   # print this leg as text, or save it to file maybe...
   text = etree.tostring(leg, pretty_print=True)
   # also process individual elements of interest here if we want
   tagsOfInterest=["noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds", "lengthInMeters", "departureTime", "trafficDelayInSeconds"]  # whatever
   #list to use for data analysis
   global data
   data = []
   #create header dictionary that includes the data to be appended within it. IE, Header = {TrafficDelay[data(0)]...etc
   for child in leg:
       if 'summary' in child.tag:
          for elem in child:
              for item in tagsOfInterest:
                  if item in elem.tag:
                      data.append(elem.text)


def parseXML(xmlFile):
"""While option
   lastTime = time.time() - 600
   while time.time() >= lastTime + 600:
    lastTime += 600"""
   #Parse the xml
   threading.Timer(5.0, parseXML).start()
   with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/-37.79205923474775,145.03010268799338:-37.798883995180496,145.03040309540322:-37.807106781970354,145.02895470253526:-37.80320743019992,145.01021142594075:-37.7999012967757,144.99318476311566:?routeType=shortest&key=xxx&computeTravelTimeFor=all") as fobj:
       xml = fobj.read()

   root = etree.fromstring(xml)

   for child in root:
       if 'route' in child.tag:
           handleLeg(child)
           # Write CSV file
           with open('datafile.csv', 'w') as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=' ')
            # writer.writerow(["your", "header", "foo"])  # write header
            writer.writerows(data)
           """for elem in child:
               if 'leg' in elem.tag:
                   handleLeg(elem)
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
   parseXML("xmlFile")

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, quotechar='"')
    # next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    data_read = [row for row in reader]

print(data_read)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know it runs only once?  Have you debugged it or do you expect to have the correct result when code reaches this part?

```
with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as fp:
    ....
```

And in general, what do you expect to happen, and when is your program supposed to enter this part?  I do not know how to fix this without knowing what you want it to do, but I think I know where your problem is.

This is what your program does. I will call the main thread M:

1. M: `if __main__()` matches and `parseXML` is called
2. M: `parseXML` launches a new thread, which we call T1, with `threading.Timer()`
3. M: `parseXML` finishes and `with open...` reached.   T1: sleep(5)
4. M: print(data_read)    T1: still probably in sleep(5)
5. M: exit - just waits for other threads to terminate  T1: `parseXML`
6. M: - T1: launches a new thread T2
7. M: - T1: completes `parseXML`  T2: sleep(5)
8. M: - T1: thread exits T2: still in sleep(5)
9. M: - T1: - T2: `parseXML`
10. M: - T1: - T2: launches a new thread T3
11. ...

How your program is built, `parseXML` (probably - not able to run your code but it looks about right) does launch a delayed copy of itself in a new thread, but your main program that handles the results has already exited and does not read your datafile.csv anymore after a new timed thread has modified it.

You can verify this by setting `daemon=True` on your threads (meaning the threads will exit as soon as your main program exits). Now your program does not "hang". It displays results after the first iteration of `parseXML` and it kills immediately the timed thread:

```
#Parse the xml
   _t = threading.Timer(5.0, parseXML)
   _t.daemon = True
   _t.start()
   with urllib.request.urlopen(....)
```

Do you really need threads here at all? Or could you just move the datafile.csv processing and display to parseXML, put a while True loop there and sleep 5 seconds between iterations?

Another possibility is to move the data reader part to another thread that would sleep N seconds and then run the reader.  **BUT** in this case you will need locks.  If you process the same file in different threads, eventually the unexpected will happen and your writer has written only a part of your file when the reader decides to read it. Your parser will then most likely crash to a syntax error. To avoid this, create a global lock and use it to protect your file read and write operations:

```
foo = threading.Lock()
....
....

with foo:
    with open(...) as fp:
        ....
```

Now your file operations stay atomic.

Sorry about the lengthy explanation, hope this helps.

Comment: This is a seriously amazing answer. I can see where i've gone wrong - I know nothing about debugging and am using python anywhere to do all of this.

Comment: How would I go about creating a while True loop and sleep as you have said would be a good way of approaching this?

Comment: Attempting to implement a whlie true loop

Comment: You could consider moving the read part into parsexml as the final item after for loop. Then you could encapsulate it all in while True: and have as the ultimate statement in this loop sleep(5).  Then you would not have multiple threads and all the complexity that comes out of it, and things would happen sequentially in the correct order.

Comment: Or even if you kept your threaded structure as such, I think you should consider moving the reader to parsexml.   If you plan to have N iterations in threads and then finally process the results (or keep processing XML until a condition is reached), your program does not currently do that.

Comment: It would help to understand what your goal is. Do you want to have an infinite loop that processes XML data, and another function that does something to the data converted to csv?   Or is there a set number of iterations, you want to collate all converted data into one large CSV and then finally do something with it?  And if you want to process data in the same program, why do you write the csv file? Would you be better off with in-memory structures, helping to get around many pitfalls, and more effective as well?